# Repeated Opening of Activity with ImageView causes out of memory error

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, repeat

I have a basic application which has a button which opens an activity via an intent and passes a random number between 1 and 9 which is used to display an image.

The images are png files of approximately 280KB in size each.

The general use of the app displays the result activity and then the user hits the back button and clicks the button again to start the activity to display another random image.
This works fine, however, after about 6 or 7 goes, I get an out of memory error relating to the respective setBackgroundResource line in the ResultActivity:

```
result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result2);
```

I've tried numerous methods of "unbindDrawables" forcing garbage collections, setting imageView to null etc but nothing seems to work.

Surely with such a basic app, I'm missing something simple here?

The intent is called via a press on a button as shown:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void displayResult(View view) {
        int randomNum = minimum + (int) (Math.random() * maximum);
        Log.d(TAG, "result" + randomNum);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, randomNum);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The Activity to display the image is shown below

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView result_image;
    protected static final String TAG = "ResultActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int message = intent.getIntExtra(ThumbMain.EXTRA_MESSAGE, 1);
        result_image = null;

        result_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        TextView result_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_title);
        TextView result_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_description);

        Log.d(TAG, "message=" + message);
        switch (message) {
        case 1:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result1);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result1_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result1_description);
            break;
        case 2:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result2);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result2_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result2_description);
            break;
        case 3:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result3);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result3_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result3_description);
            break;
        case 4:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result4);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result4_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result4_description);
            break;
        case 5:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result5);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result5_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result5_description);
            break;
        case 6:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result6);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result6_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result6_description);
            break;
        case 7:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result7);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result7_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result7_description);
            break;
        case 8:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result8);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result8_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result8_description);
            break;
        case 9:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result9);
            result_title.setText(R.string.result9_title);
            result_description.setText(R.string.result9_description);
            break;
        default:
            result_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result1);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The xml of the activity is here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.example.android.ResultActivity"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Stack Trace:

```
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561): Process: org.example.android.exampletest, PID: 29561
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3426)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1898)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16235)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at org.example.android.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:50)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
01-13 22:44:20.545: E/AndroidRuntime(29561):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try putting your images in the drawable-nodpi folder instead of drawable

Comment: Calculate `imageWidth * imageHeight * 4 / 1024 / 1024`. You'll get the size of the image in memory in MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from samgak - "Try putting your images in the drawable-nodpi folder instead of drawable" resolved the issue.

Many Thanks.